# For Diskstation: Which type of product should I choose?

Tags: magento-1.7, product-type

In one Diskstation there are 4 to 20 or more bays where we can keep our Drives of storage 500GB,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10TB inside each bay.

Let us say I have diskstation of 4 Bays So total 40TB can be stored in it. Each bay can hold maximum 10TB in it.

Let us say Diskstation price is $100
500 GB Drive Price is $10
1 TB Price is $20 and so on

So customer will see diskstation product at $100
And he can choose in 1st bay what storage capacity he needs,
he can choose in 2nd bay what storage capacity he needs,
he can choose in 3rd bay what storage capacity he needs..

My question is that which product type should i choose and how to do this?

Because in 4 bays product, each bay have 9 Choice. And there is some products with 20 bays also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using "Custom Options" in Magento which has solved my problem of creating 100s of product

Answer (score 1):

`Configurable` Type product may fulfill your need.

1. You can created multiple attributes as required to use in configurable products.
2. Based on that attribute selection in product page Magento default system will work.